# Заполнение таблицы

Tags: php

```
<?php
    function status($value)
    {
       $res=mysql_query("SELECT `status_name` FROM `status`");
       echo "<select name='status'>"; 
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            foreach($row as $a)
            {
                echo "<option value='".$a."'";
                if($value==$a)
                {
                    echo 'selected';
                } 
                echo ">".$a."</option>";

            }
        }
        echo "</select>";

    }
    function emploe($value)
    {
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT `emploe_name` FROM `emploe` WHERE `emploe_role`='user'");
        echo "<select name='emploe'>"; 
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            foreach($row as $a)
            {
                echo "<option value='".$a."'";
                if($value==$a)
                {
                    echo 'selected';
                } 
                echo ">".$a."</option>";

            }

    }
    echo "</select>";

    }
    function pre_show_table()
    {
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT `project_id`,`project_name`,`date_start`,`date_finish` FROM `projects`");
        echo "<table >";
        echo "<tr ><td>Project Name</td><td>Date Start</td><td>Date Finish</td><td>Select</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['project_name'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['date_start'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['date_finish'].'</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="project_select" value="'.$row['project_id'].'"/></td>
            </tr>';

         }
         echo "</table>";
    }
    function admin_show($id)
    {
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr >
                <td>Project Name</td>
                <td>Date Start</td>
                <td>Date Finish</td>
                <td>TZ</td>
                <td>TZ Status</td>
                <td>Design</td>
                <td>Design Status</td>
                <td>Verstka</td>
                <td>Verstka Status</td>
                <td>Proger</td>
                <td>Proger Status</td>
                <td>Sdacha</td>

        </tr>";
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `project_id`='".$id."'");

        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
        {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['project_name'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['date_start'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['date_finish'].'</td>
                    <td>'.emploe($row['TZ']).'</td>
                    <td>'.status($row['TZ_st']).'</td>
                    <td>'.emploe($row['designer']).'</td>
                    <td>'.status($row['designer_st']).'</td>
                    <td>'.emploe($row['verstka']).'</td>
                    <td>'.status($row['verstka_st']).'</td>
                    <td>'.emploe($row['proger']).'</td>
                    <td>'.status($row['proger_st']).'</td>
                    <td>'.status($row['Sdacha']).'</td>

            </tr>';

         }
         echo "</table>";
    }

    admin_show(6);
?>
```

Функция `admin_show` не рисует в таблицу, функции `emploe()` и `status()` вызываются. Кто может, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

у Вас точно есть ошибка тут

```
="" echo="" 'selected';="" }="" echo="" "="">
```

После echo не ставиться знак =. Это не единственное место с подобной ситуацией.

Помимо всего в функции admin_show есть еще такая проблема. В строчке

```
 $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

Вы потеряли слово **while**. Должно быть что-то вроде:

```
While($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
```

А вообще я бы на Вашем месте задумался о том, что весь код нужно переписать по новому. А то, как то логика не ясна...